# SQL Server : remove duplicated text within a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, duplicates

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with a column containing lengthy HTML text. Near the top there is a link provided for an associated MP3 file which is unique to each record. The links are are all formatted as follows:

```
<div class="MediaSaveAs"><a href="filename??.mp3">Download Audio </a></div>
```

Unfortunately many records contain two or three sequential and identical instances of this link where there should be only one. Is there a relatively simple script I can run to find and eliminate the redundant links?

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what your data looks like or what results you need, but do you have to do this in TSQL? It's a very poor language for working with text, so it would be far easier to use a script in some other language. You could write a CLR procedure, but a language like Python or Perl that has libraries for parsing HTML might be even simpler.

Comment: Thanks - I am pretty much limited to what I can run as a script in SQL Mgmt Studio; it's pretty much just a repeated text issue, the fact that it is HTML may not matter much.

Comment: You still need to show some sample data: it isn't clear from your question if the entire `div` class is repeated in the column, or only the anchor element, or only the filename or whatever. You also haven't said *why* you can only use TSQL (or if you can use a CLR procedure); with that information someone may have a completely different and easier solution.

Comment: there is other text above and below the sample line I gave in the first post - that identical line will occur three times where it should be just once.  The only difference from record to record is the filename. Sorry, my skills are limited to short scripts - if a CLR would work someone would have to walk me through implementing it.

Comment: Unfortunately your comment is a little confusing: your question says "identical instances of this link" but your comments say "the only difference...is the filename". So are they identical or not? I strongly suggest that you stop describing your problem in words and post sample data and expected results, otherwise we will struggle to help you.

Comment: Each record (row) in my table has a column (field) containing a lot of text (transcript of voice recording).  Near the top of that text there is supposed to be a single link for the associated MP3 download.  Obviously the filename changes from row to row. But the link got repeated WITHIN a single row's text field.  So where, in a single field, it should be [text][link][text] some of them have [text][link][link][link][text].  Hope that clarifies my initial question - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure - because your explanation wasn't very clear - but this appears to do what you want, although whether or not you consider this to be a  "simple script", I don't know.

```
declare @Link nvarchar(200) = N'<div class="MediaSaveAs"><a href="filename123.mp3">Download Audio </a></div>'

declare @BadData nvarchar(max) = N'cbjahcgfhjasgfzhjaucv' + replicate(@Link, 3) + N'cabhjcsghagj',
        @StartPattern nvarchar(34) = N'<div class="MediaSaveAs"><a href="',
        @EndPattern nvarchar(27) = N'">Download Audio </a></div>'

select @BadData

select replace (
    @BadData,
    substring(@BadData, charindex(@StartPattern, @BadData), len(@BadData)-charindex(reverse(@EndPattern), reverse(@BadData))-charindex(@StartPattern, @BadData) + 2),
    substring(@BadData, charindex(@StartPattern, @BadData), charindex(@EndPattern, @BadData) + len(@EndPattern) - charindex(@StartPattern, @BadData))
)
```

Personally I would not like to have to maintain this code; I would far rather use a script in another language that can actually parse HTML. You said this is "just a repeated text issue", but that doesn't mean it's an easy problem and especially not in a language like TSQL that has such limited support for string operations.

For future reference, please put all relevant information into the question - you can edit it if you need to - instead of leaving them in the comments where they are difficult to read and may be overlooked. And please post sample data and results instead of describing things in words.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to identify the file names, which we can do with PATINDEX:

```
select 
    substring(html, PATINDEX('%filename%.mp3%', html), PATINDEX('%.mp3%', html)-PATINDEX('%filename%.mp3%', html)+4)
from files
```

And then secondly identify and  the duplicates, check it out:

```
delete 
from files 
where id not in (
    select max(id) 
    from files 
    group by substring(html, PATINDEX('%filename%.mp3%', html), PATINDEX('%.mp3%', html)-PATINDEX('%filename%.mp3%', html)+4)
  )
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/887a3/5